# GIT Workflow - Confused

Tags: git, workflow, release

i've a question about git workflows.

We're 20 developers, developing a web based application with PHP.
This application is modular, this means we have a core system and different modules.

Our customers buys some modules and get this and the core.

Currently we have three different servers: dev, beta and release.
All of this three servers are mounted over network on PCs. That means all developers are working under one network mount.

Now we want to establish a git workflow. But i'm confused how to do that, because no developer has a local copy. Why? We need live preview over apache2.

How can we integrate git in our current system?

We also need a system to create releases based on our modules.

I hope to get input :)

Comment: Why can't you run apache locally? Especially with options like docker available today...

Comment: It seems you're not ready to implement git **in your current system** because your current system doesn't lend itself easily to using version control. You need to change your current system to be local development, which means each developer needs a local development environment including a test environment for running the code in. Only then will you be ready for using version control.